# A value of type 'Future<List>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'

Tags: flutter, sqlite, casting, future

I am really newbie in Flutter and SQLite.
I need to store some data got from a DB into a global variable (in this code it's a local variable just for exemplification) and I don't know:

1. where is the best point I can do it (now I put it in the homepage's initState method);
2. how I can store future data in a no-future variable.

Below is the method for the data extraction

```
class ObjectRepository {
  ObjectRepository._(); 
  static final ObjectRepository instance = ObjectRepository._();

  Future<List<Map>> select(Database db, String tableName, {List<String> fields}) async {
        sql = 'SELECT ' + (fields != null ? fields.toString() : '* ');
        sql = sql + 'FROM $tableName';
    
        final List<Map> list = await db.rawQuery(sql);
    
        return list;
  }
}
```

Below is where I put my future<List<Map>> into a List<Map> (I know I can't, in fact the IDE gives me this error *A value of type 'Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'*.

I even tried to cast it, but I got a similar issue at run-time *"type 'Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' in type cast"*.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    DBProvider.instance.openDB(globalConstants.dbName);
    List<Map> list = ObjectRepository.instance.select(DBProvider.instance.database, 'tCars') as List<Map>;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    DBProvider.instance.closeDB();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(title: Text('Cars')),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      body: CustomBody(),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea how can I resolve it? Many thanks, folks.

Comment: It's a Future.  You have to await it somewhere.  Don't be in such a hurry. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from database is an asynchronous activity, which means the query doesn't return some data immediately. so you have to wait for the operation to complete and then assign it to a variable.

```
DBProvider.instance.openDB(globalConstants.dbName);
List<Map> list = await ObjectRepository.instance.select(DBProvider.instance.database, 'tCars') as List<Map>;
```

On the other hand, you can not use `await` inside `initState`.
The solution is to create an `async` function that handles the process of getting data from database.

```
Future<List<Map>> initDB()async{
  DBProvider.instance.openDB(globalConstants.dbName);
  List<Map> list = await ObjectRepository.instance.select(DBProvider.instance.database, 'tCars') as List<Map>;
  return list;
}
```

finally you can call `initDB` inside `initState`

Comment: _On the other hand, you can not use await inside initState. The solution is to create an async function that handles the process of getting data from database. 
Finally you can call initDB inside initState_ This works for me: simple, effective for a newbie like me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Error is because `instant.select` function returns the `Future<List<Map>>` but you are tring to asign it to `List<Map>` therefore you have to await until the `future` completes. but the `initState` is not an `async` function. therefore you cannot `await` there. but you can use `then` method on future (which is called when future is completed with the value). and give it the `callback` (action you want to perform with the value) to then method. But you have to careful to check whether the `list` is null or not before you using it by `if` statement because it is set to null initially.

```dart
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      List<Map>? list;
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        DBProvider.instance.openDB(globalConstants.dbName);
        ObjectRepository.instance.select(DBProvider.instance.database, 'tCars').then((result){
           if(mounted) {
             setState((){ list = result});
              }else { list = result}
            });
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        DBProvider.instance.closeDB();
    
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: CustomAppBar(title: Text('Cars')),
          drawer: CustomDrawer(),
          body: CustomBody(),
        );
      }
    }
```

Instant of this if you are tring to use your list for a widget (eg: ListView). consider using `FutureBuilder` which takes `future` and `builder` function to return appropriate `widget` according to the state of the future you have given to it. For Example,

```dart
 FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
   future: ObjectRepository.instance.select(DBProvider.instance.database, 'tCars') // your future here,
builder : (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.hasError) return ErorrScreen();
       if (snapshot.hasData) return ListView.builder(itemCount :  snapshot.data.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return Text(snpshot.data[index].toString());
});
return CicularProgressIndicator();
}
)
```

this is the more recommended way of using futures in your UI in flutter.